# Trying to center text vertically and horizontally next to an image

Tags: html, css, text, center

https://github.com/Yankysamurai/Personal-Website-P5

I am new to posting questions but I am trying to center my text "Welcome to my site" horizontally and vertically. I want it half the distance from the image and from the right margin. I tried display flex but it didn't work.

I just opened a git hub account so I hope you can see the code from the link.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the `flex` container has an `img` and `h2`. In order to vertically center the text (relative to the image), you need to set `align-items: center;`

```
.about_img_h2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I would suggest using `jsfiddle` next time, because it makes it easier to review the problem. I created this one (using the GitHub repo you shared) with the fix:
https://jsfiddle.net/13sc4m76/

Let me know if I misunderstood your question and I can take a second look.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following ways to center elements in a block:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center
```

or

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center
```